# ListView loses position after updating adapter listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(...))

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

When end items in a ListView, i upload new, and after update adapter:

```
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
boxAdapter = null;
boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);
lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
```

But after this, elements are loaded but the scroll position the top. Ie the position of ListView is lost, and look again at the beginning of all

How fix it?

BoxAdapter code:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private final Context ctx;
      private final LayoutInflater lInflater;
      private final ArrayList<ItemInfo> objects;
      private final int loadCount = 10;
      private int count = 10;
      private String name, desc;

      BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemInfo> products) {

        this.ctx = context;
        this.objects = products;
        this.lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      }



      // кол-во элементов
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        //return objects.size();
          return this.count;
      }

      // элемент по позиции
      @Override
      public ItemInfo getItem(int position) {
          return objects.get(position);
      }

      // id по позиции
      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }

      public void loadAdditionalItems() {
            this.count += this.loadCount;
            if (this.count > this.objects.size()) {
                this.count = this.objects.size();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
      }



      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        ItemInfo p = getItem(position);
        TextView desc_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        if (p.username.contains("null"))
        {
            name = "Автор: Неизвестен";
        }
        else
        {
           name = "Автор: " + p.username;
        }

        if(!p.description.contains("null"))
        {
            desc = p.description.replaceAll("<br />", "");
            desc = desc.replaceAll("&quot;", "");
        }
        else
        {
            desc = "";
            desc_id.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(desc);
        return view;
      }

}
```

P.S setOnScrollListener code:

```
lvMain.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                        boxAdapter.loadAdditionalItems();
                        loading = false;
                    }
                    if (!loading && (lvMain.getLastVisiblePosition() + 10) >= (60))
                    {
                        new LoadLastestPost().execute();
                        loading = true;
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
```

Comment: Use `ViewHolder` pattern for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to create a `setProducts` method in your `boxAdapter` and then just call `boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. For example:

```
boxAdapter.setProducts(products);
boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you implement this method, there is no need to call `lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter)` more than once.

To add the `setProducts()` method to your adapter:

```
public BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ItemInfo> objects;

    public BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemInfo> products) {
        mContext = context;
        objects = products;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate and adjust view
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public void setProducts(ArrayList<ItemInfo> newData) {
        objects = newData;
    }
}
```

Also, I wouldn't use a `count` variable. I would just use the `size` method in the `ArrayList`. I would remove `count` altogether.

Comment: What do I do when I call this function in the adapter?

Comment: If the rest of your adapter is set up properly, those two methods should be enough to refresh the list and keep you at the same position in the list. You shouldn't have to do anything more.

Comment: this i understand, but i dont understand how add product in adapter in the class adapter.

Comment: I'll try my best to update my answer, but it would be helpful if you posted your `BoxAdapter` code.